# TeamCity - Building dotnet core web api project using cake script

Tags: .net-core, teamcity, cakebuild

Running Cake Build script on my local machine works fine but when same script is run on TeamCity, the following error appears: Nuspec file does not exist in package.

[image]

Any idea what could have caused this error?

Comment: go to the packages folder on your hard drive and delete all its contents. After that restore packages

Comment: @SeniorPomidor I tried this but I am still getting this error. When I build the project from the TeamCity/Works directory using the build.cake file, it build successfully.

Comment: then just build from this directory.

Comment: @SeniorPomidor I want TeamCity to trigger the build automatically rather than running it manually.

Comment: I want to say just set the working directory as TeamCity/Works. and build

Comment: I had a similar problem with TFS 2017. Build was always red with same message, but when I tried in a console, it worked. Turns out that the reason why it worked was my user: When I started the console with the same user the build uses, I got the same error. So I deleted everything in `<builduser home>/.nuget/packages/*`, after that the build worked again.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I spent two days due to this error
On `dotnet build --configuration Release` in TeamCity PowerShell, always got this error

```
error NU5000: Nuspec file does not exist in package
```

After deleting this folder, everything worked `C:/Users/teamcity_user/.nuget`

Comment: Thanks for saving me 2 days ;)

Answer (score 3):

I add an additional step on top of my build steps which is a command line custom script

```
dotnet nuget locals --clear all
```

[image: Build Step to clear nuget locals]